# Problems with comments callback (Argument #1 is not an array?)

Tags: comments, errors, callbacks

I built my callback function using [class-walker-comment.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php) as a reference and am at a loss as to why it's not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The issues I'm encountering are:

1) Avatars don't display.

2) This error displays above every comment:

> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array

The error appears to be the result of this bit of code in my function:

```
comment_reply_link(array_merge
```

Here's the full callback function I'm using:

```
function custom_comment( $comment, $depth, $args ) { 

$tag = ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) ? 'div' : 'li'; ?>

<<?php echo $tag; ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class( $args['has_children'] ? 'parent' : '', $comment ); ?>>

    <article id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment-inner">
    <div class="comment-header"> 

    <?php  
    if ( 0 != $args['avatar_size'] ) { ?>

        <div class="comment-avatar">
            <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

        <div class="comment-meta-wrap">
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
            <!--  translators: %s: comment author link -->
            <?php printf(   __( '%s <span class="says">says:</span>' ), sprintf( '<b class="fn">%s</b>', get_comment_author_link( $comment ) ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .comment-author -->

        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">

        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment, $args ) ); ?>">
        <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>">
        <!-- translators: 1: comment date, 2: comment time -->
            <?php printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s' ), get_comment_date( '', $comment ), get_comment_time() ); ?>
        </time>
        </a>

        <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>

        </div><!-- .comment-meta -->

        </div><!-- .comment-meta-wrap -->

        </div><!-- .comment-header --> <div class="clearboth"></div>

        <div class="comment-content">

        <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
            <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php comment_text(); ?>

        </div><!-- .comment-content -->

        <?php
        comment_reply_link(
            array_merge(
                $args, array(
                    'add_below' => 'div-comment',
                    'depth'     => $depth,
                    'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
                    'before'    => '<div class="reply">',
                    'after'     => '</div>',
                )
            )
        ); ?>

        </article><!-- .comment-inner -->
```

And here's my comments.php:

```
<?php
// You can start editing here -- including this comment!
if ( have_comments() ) :
?>
    <h2 class="comments-title">
        <?php
        $comments_number = get_comments_number();
        if ( '1' === $comments_number ) {
            /* translators: %s: post title */
            printf( _x( 'One Reply to &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'comments title', 'textdomain' ), get_the_title() );
        } else {
            printf(
                /* translators: 1: number of comments, 2: post title */
                _nx(
                    '%1$s Reply to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    '%1$s Replies to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    $comments_number,
                    'comments title',
                    'textdomain'
                ),
                number_format_i18n( $comments_number ),
                get_the_title()
            );
        }
        ?>
    </h2>

    <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            wp_list_comments(
                array(
                    'avatar_size' => 100,
                    'style'       => 'ol',
                    'callback'    => 'custom_comment',
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                )
            );
        ?>
    </ol>

    <?php
    the_comments_pagination(
        array(
            'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous', 'textdomain' ) . '</span>',
            'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next', 'textdomain' ) . '</span>',
        )
    );

endif; // Check for have_comments().

// If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
?>

    <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'textdomain' ); ?></p>
<?php
endif;

comment_form();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try var_dump on the array_merge & avatar parameters? That would tell you if the variables are what you expect.

Anyway - it looks like you have the parameter order wrong.

You are using

```
custom_comment( $comment, $depth, $args )
```

but it should be

```
custom_comment( $comment, $args, $depth )
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think that would do it! Can also be avoided if task is done with a custom comment Walker object instead of a callback.

Comment: I can't believe that's what the issue ended up being! Thank You(!) for taking the time to come over.. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries - I'm sure we have all done similar things at one time or another, I know I have! :)